# Retain select dropdown value after an ajax refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

This could be a repetitive question but please bare me. I have a dropdown as below, 
I select the option yellow, I have onclick which would do an operation and this does an ajax call. So after the ajax call the dropdown is defaulted back to red option instead of staying on yellow. I am still learning jquery

```
<select onChange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].onclick();>
<option value="red" onclick="">red</option>
<option value="yellow" onclick="">yellow</option>
<option value="blue" onclick="">blue</option>
<option value="green" onclick="">green</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's your JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

A rough example as to how you achieve this:

```
// before ajax
var selected_item = $('select').val(); // use a better selector

// do some ajax
$.ajax({
    url: '/',
    data: {
        foo: 'bar'
    }
    success: function(data) {

        // update the select
        $('select').html(data);

        // reapply the originally selected element
        $('select').val(selected_item);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('input[value=red]').ajaxSuccess(function(){
   $(this).prop('selected', true)
})
```