# PHP AJAX JSON Drop Down value on form submission

Tags: php, ajax, json, drop-down-menu, reload

I want to retain the value of the drop down when the form is submitted. I have two drop down- Department and Project interlinked through AJAX. When I submit, the page is reloaded, and by default the values of the department and the project comes out to be All Departments and All projects, however I wish to retain the value selected by the user.

This is the code. Pardon the rest of the code if missing as I am showing only the required code.

```
    <html><head><script type="text/Javascript">

        function showdept(){
            $('#deptdropdown').empty();
            $('#deptdropdown').append("<option value='0'> All Departments </option>");
            $('#projectdropdown').append("<option value='0'> All Projects </option>");
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"departmentdropdown.php",
                contentType:"application/json; charset:utf-8",
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(data){
                    $('#deptdropdown').empty();
                    $('#deptdropdown').append("<option value='0'> All Departments </option>");
                    $.each(data,function(i,item){
                        $('#deptdropdown').append('<option value="'+ data[i].deptID +'">'+ data[i].deptname +'</option>');
                    });
                },
                complete: function(){
                }
            });
        }

        function showproject(deptID){       
            $('#projectdropdown').empty();
            $('#projectdropdown').append("<option value='0'> All Projects </option>");          
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"projectdropdown.php?dID="+deptID,
                contentType:"application/json; charset:utf-8",
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(data){
                    $('#projectdropdown').empty();
                    $('#projectdropdown').append("<option value='0'> All Projects </option>");
                    $.each(data,function(i,item){
                        $('#projectdropdown').append('<option value="'+ data[i].proID +'">'+ data[i].projectname+'</option>');
                    });
                },
                complete: function(){
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){               //Initial call to the functions.

            showdept();                             //Shows all the departments.

            $("#deptdropdown").change(function(){   //When department changes, call the project function
                var deptid=$("#deptdropdown").val();
                showproject(deptid);
            });</script></head><body><div id="container" style="min-height:500px; border-bottom:2px solid grey"><div id="verticaldropdown" style="width:200px; background:yellow; border-right: 1px solid grey; min-height:500px; float:left">
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <div align="center">
        <div>Department</div>
        <div><select name="dept_selected" style="width:160px" id="deptdropdown"></select></div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div align="center">
        <div>Project</div>
        <div><select name="project_selected" style="width:160px" id="projectdropdown"></select></div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div align="center">
        <input type=submit value='Go' name='showcompliance'>
        </div>
    </form> 
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you might want to take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455199/retain-select-dropdown-value-after-an-ajax-refresh it could help you get started, just edit your post with the things you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the dept and project ids for selected the choosen:

```
$.each(data,function(i,item){
 if(data[i].deptID==choosen_dept){
    $('#deptdropdown').append('<option value="'+ data[i].deptID +'" selected>'+ data[i].deptname +'</option>');
 }else{
    $('#deptdropdown').append('<option value="'+ data[i].deptID +'">'+ data[i].deptname +'</option>');
 }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I compared the data[i].deptID with the $_POST[dept_value] and it worked.

Comment: Maybe the thing ollierexx said is good solution too, draw the <options> in php and returns it directly. As you prefers, the both works.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to fix this issue:
1) You can submit the form using AJAX, and this will not clear the selections in the form
2) You can use PHP to pre-fill the values in the dropdowns after the page has been refreshed.
Please choose one and I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I could make the selection stay using the above code snippet, but I am curious to know how I can submit the form using AJAX ? Please share it.